# Docsify search plugin. Accents marks

Tags: search, docsify

It posible that search plugin ignore accents marks (tildes) ?

for example: i want that the

> articulo

to be the same the

> artículo

and reverse.

thx!

Answer (score 1):

docsify has supported since v4.12.0. https://github.com/docsifyjs/docsify/releases/tag/v4.12.0